# Firefox CSS error

Tags: css, firefox

Please visit http://domenadesign.com/istra-bike.com with Firefox browser!

After a few clicks on the links page go crazy but only in Firefox, what's the problem?
I tried to experiment with anything in css (position, float...) but it doesnt work properly..

Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try and make sure your code is valid first:

http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http://domenadesign.com/istra-bike.com/

One thing I noticed right of the bat is that you have a DIV inside of an Anchor.

If you can get your page to pass validation, your problems will most likely solve itself.

Comment: True but don't forget that if he has code that generates this he will have to find his bug. Using a validator would not fix this if that is the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:
Two `divs` in an `a` tag

```
<a class="link_button" href="">
    <div class="slideshow">
        <img src="images/club/klub_5.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="link_button_name">MTB Club - Racing Team</div>
</a>
```

You have this problem more than once, I found an other one its similar so I won't post an other snippet.

You most likely have code that generates this layout and its just a logical bug. I noticed that if I click on them a certain way it does this.

There could be more problems.